# How to GetProfile by custom properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile, asp.net-profiles

```
<profile enabled="true" automaticSaveEnabled="false">
  <properties>
    <add name="InvitationCode" type="String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

How to get profiles with InvitationCode="foo"?
Also can i make property unique?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you have web site or web application it could be two ways.
for web site `Profile.InvitationCode` and `Profile.GetPropertyValue("InvitationCode")` for Web Application